# azure cloud service port forwarding

Tags: azure, port, forwarding

I have a cloud service - CS1. I have two IaaS Linux VMs in CS1. Lets call the vms - vm1 and vm2.

CS1, vm1 and vm2 are all in one vnet in one region.

Both vms have internal ips and have ssh setup.

The endpoints are setup as follows:

VM    NAme   Protocol    Public Port     Private Port

vm1    SSH     TCP          22              22

vm2    SSH     TCP          23              22

No ACLs on the endpoints. No firewalls on the linux machines.

I can ssh into vm1 using port 22 like so -  ssh -p 22 user1@cs1.cloudapp.net
but I cant ssh into vm2 using port 23 -  ssh -p 23 user2@cs1.cloudapp.net

Once I ssh into vm1 , then I can ssh into vm2 using vm2's private ip. 
Why can i not ssh into vm2 using the public address. Is there some cloud service setting or some azure firewall or anything im missing here?

Comment: Any ideas, pointers .... PLease suggest Im willing to try it. Thank You